# What is difference between int.class and Integer.TYPE in java?

Tags: java

I want to know the difference between int.class and Integer.TYPE in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer.class vs int.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470985/integer-class-vs-int-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **.class** keyword get the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object represent both primitive types and class types, while the **.TYPE** field of the [wrapper primitive class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) allows you to get the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) of the primitive type which that object wraps.

Comment: Isn't that `.class` just a syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 16):

Absolutely nothing.  If you run the following code, you will see that `int.class` is the same thing as `Integer.TYPE`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(int.class == Integer.TYPE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

absolutely false check this :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(int.class.equals(Integer.TYPE));
            System.out.println(Integer.class.equals(Integer.TYPE));
        }
```

output :
true 
false

```
Boolean.TYPE == boolean.class 
Byte.TYPE == byte.class 
Short.TYPE == short.class 
Character.TYPE == char.class 
Integer.TYPE == int.class 
Long.TYPE == long.class 
Float.TYPE == float.class 
Double.TYPE == double.class 
Void.TYPE == void.class
```

Comment: That's correct output. As `Integer` does indeed *not* wrap `Integer`.