# Difference between Integer.class and Integer.TYPE

Tags: java

What is the difference between these two? A primitive type cannot have "Class", can it - it is primitive. There are no objects to have a class.

Where does these two make a difference?

Comment: I think you meant `int.class` vs `Integer.TYPE`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - `TYPE` is a constant of the Integer class, which returns a `Class<Integer>` object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=Difference+between+Integer.class+and+Integer.TYPE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759305/what-is-difference-between-int-class-and-integer-type-in-java this is what I meant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between int.class and Integer.TYPE in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759305/what-is-difference-between-int-class-and-integer-type-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not positive what you mean, but -- A `Class` object is a runtime representative of a type.  That said, there is such a thing as `int.class` that is distinct from `Integer.class`, even though `int` is not a class.  It's kind of complicated, but it's necessary to make reflection work even on methods that take primitive arguments or return primitive values, or to distinguish a method that accepts an `Integer` from a method that accepts an `int`.

`Integer.TYPE`, I believe, is equivalent to `int.class`.

Comment: We're looking at a distant future, but according to [Oracle's Java roadmap](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2012/120315-oracle-s-java-roadmap.html), Java 10 and beyond will get rid of primitive types, thus making more or less everything in Java an object. Now if just those methods (functions!) could be made first class...

Comment: @darioo So you're basically saying that instead of `int` we will have to write `Integer`? Better get my fingers ready (**NO** not in that sense)!

Comment: @fireshadow52 - No, they will probably do what .Net does and make `int` an alias for `Integer` - otherwise pretty much all Java code predating Java10 would fail to compile (breaking the rule that Java is supposed to be code-compatible with previous versions). Transparent `Integer` object creation and usage, you won't have to do anything differently.

Comment: I really have no idea how they'll make it work with backwards-compatibility...if they plan to maintain backwards compatibility.  ::sigh::

Comment: @darioo Regarding _"Java 10 and beyond will get rid of primitive types"_, more than seven years later it seems incredible that anyone would have ever made that wildly optimistic claim!