# Integer.class vs int.class

Tags: java, reflection, primitive

What is the difference between `Integer.class`, `Integer.TYPE` and `int.class`?

acc to me

1. `Integer.class` is a reference of Integer (Wrapper) Class object
2. but what is then `int.class` as `int` is not a class, it's a primitive type. And what does `Integer.TYPE` refer to?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From `java.lang.Class.isPrimitive` API

There are nine predefined Class objects to represent the eight primitive types and void. These are created by the Java Virtual Machine, and have the same names as the primitive types that they represent, namely boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double.

These objects may only be accessed via the following public static final variables `java.lang.Boolean.TYPE`, `java.lang.Integer.TYPE` etc

Comment: That last sentence may be in the javadocs, but it's wrong. :) You can also access those objects via `int.class`, `boolean.class` etc. I don't know when that functionality came in, so maybe the docs are just out of date there?

Comment: i agree, interesting, why they said so, it's from Java 7

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev how is this supposed to be the answer? The question was **what's the difference between Integer.class, Integer.TYPE and int.class**

Answer (score 51):

`Integer.class` is, as you say, a reference to the `Class` object for the `Integer` type.

`int.class` is, similarity, a reference to the `Class` object for the `int` type. You're right that this doesn't sound right; the primitives all have a `Class` object as a special case. It's useful for reflection, if you want to tell the difference between `foo(Integer value)` and `foo(int value)`.

`Integer.TYPE` (not `Integer.type`, mind you) is just a shortcut for `int.class`.

You can get a sense of this with a simple program:

```
public class IntClasses {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<Integer> a = int.class;
    Class<Integer> b = Integer.TYPE;
    Class<Integer> c = Integer.class;

    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(c));
  }
}
```

Example output (it'll be different each time, but the first two will always be the same, and the third will virtually always be different):

```
366712642
366712642
1829164700
```

Comment: How is it a shortcut, it literally takes longer to type.

Answer (score 2):

Java handles primitive types versus class types in a schizophrenic way by defining two types for each primitive.

For instance `int` is the primitive type and `Integer` the class type. When you use generics, you are forced to use a non-primitive type so `ArrayList<Integer>` is allowed but `ArrayList<int>` not.

Since you sometimes want to perform reflection, this duality results in two classes (how else can you inspect a method `public int foo ();`).

Say you have a class:

```
public class Foo {

    private Integer value;

    public int value1 () {
        return value;
    }

    public Integer value2 () {
        return value;
    }

}
```

The two methods will not always return the same value, since `value2()` can return `null` and `value1()` will throw a runtime error.

Comment: It's not schizophrenic. Integer is a class which holds a primitive of type int. It's a wrapper, a class by itself. I could define my own wrapper holding an int. It wouldn't be an alias to int or whatsoever. The fact you can use arithmetic operations on JDK wrappers is just because the JVM unwraps the primitive when needed by itself.
There is only one type for ints, which is represented by what's returned by the call int.class. It is a totally different class from the Integer class, which is the type of the wrapper holding an int.

Comment: @MaximeOudot: yes indeed. It is just shizophrenic that there are *two* representations of the same value. Since Java 5, it also coerces often automatically between the two, which is more unsafe. Finally this also means that generics are automatically *boxed* which means there is often serious performance degradation. A higher level language should normally make abstraction for this, and let the compiler optimize this away, or for example use the type system to prevent people from using an collection of boxed `Integer`s.

Answer (score 1):

In plain terms :

> int -- > Are primitives..for simple math operations. You cannot add them
>   to a collection.
>
> Integer --> Are objects in themselves.. are wrappers  to ints. i.e,
>   they can be used with collections (as they are objects).  They are
>   collected as normal objects by the GC.

EDIT :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 5;
    System.out.println(int.class);

    Integer i1 = new Integer(5);
    System.out.println(Integer.TYPE);

}

O/P : int
      int
```

So, basically, both return an int. Integer.TYPE just returns the primitive type of the Integer class. It is true for any wrapper class

Comment: was asking what is Integer.TYPE and int.class then?

Comment: One main reason I use Wrapper Primitives is that they allow **null** value.

Comment: @cbayram - good point.. But I guess the OP already knows this. :)

Answer (score 1):

To me, the easiest way to understand `int.class` and `Integer.class` is to stop thinking `Integer` is a wrapper (which kind of implies it is "special"). In fact, it is easier, and probably more appropriate, to think of int as a special case.

Integer is just a normal Java class, nothing different from e.g. String. It derives from `Object`, operates like `Object`, At runtime you can create an instance of `Integer`, the instance takes an object-like memory layout, e.g. with a pointer at the beginning pointing to the `Integer.class`, which is what enables the polymorphic runtime behavior of java.

There is really nothing special yet about `Integer`. if you imagine a Java without boolean, int, long these primitives, but only with Integer, Boolean, Long etc, the type system is actually very consistent.

Conceptually, you can think of `int` as a special **class** introduced later for performance reasons. Initially, it has nothing to do with Integer. At the time when Java was created, maintaining an object-like memory layout for plain numbers is very expensive for arithmetic heavy programs. And most of the arithmetic operations do not even involve polymorphic dynamic dispatching at all. E.g. it is a lot less common to invoke methods such as toString on a number.

int is special in the sense that it is a class whose "*instances*" are laid out in memory with the common object structure stripped off - just four consecutive bytes with no extra meta data.

As a result, you cannot do `123.getClass()` because the runtime memory layout of int 123 does not have a class pointer. `int.class` does exist, it is completely unrelated to `Integer.class` (yet). In a sense, int is more similar to Void, as in Void.class does exist, but you can never have object o where `o.class == Void.class`.

Java could just settle here, int is int, Integer is Integer. But what people realize is that although less common, it is still very useful to be able treat int as a normal Java object otherwise you will always have to maintain two sets of your methods at least - one that takes normal objects, and another one that takes primitives - even though performance is not your concern. In these scenarios, int is actually behaving like Integer. Java allows this conversion to automatically happen through the processes of auto-boxing, hence effectively making int and Integer related.

But int is still int, and Integer is still Integer (e.g. `int.class != Integer.class`). But one extra field is introduced to Integer.class to indicate it relates to int.class, that is `Integer.TYPE`. So `Integer.TYPE == int.class`. **To me `Integer.TYPE` is just to capture the notional that Integer and int are related**. How to use it, or whether it is even useful, is up to you.

In practice, int and Integer are still separate types where it matters. For example:

```
void accept (int value);
void accept (Integer value);
```

are still considered two overloads. Hence when working with reflection, you can use int.class and Integer.class to differentiate between the two.

When not working with reflection or some form of meta programming, because you cannot navigate to int.class from an object, it is relatively rare to see int.class to be used in your code. Sometimes it feels confusing because auto-boxing syntax seems to suggest you should be getting int.class:

```
int value = 1;
Class c = ((Object)value).getClass();
```

But that is just an illusion, as the moment you do `((Object)value)`, you are actually creating a new Integer instance with the same value.

The only time I need to explicitly work with int.class and Integer.class is to build a generics api `<T> T getValue(String name, Class<T> type);` where I need to differentiate if the api is allowed to return null:

```
int value = getValue("key", Integer.class); // will potentially throw NPE
int value = getValue("key", int.class); // will never throw NPE
```