# JAVA - Primitive type VS Object type

Tags: java, class, reflection, types

I have following variables:

```
Class a = int.class;
Class b = Integer.class;
```

Is it possible to compare it dynamically? It means that I want to get primitive tye of second variable and compare it with first.

Comment: `int` **isn't** a `class`.

Comment: It is not the same type. there are only conversions (natural) between them.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but it's legal statement and it works.

Comment: I want to dynamically compare types. E.g int with Integer will be TRUE, int with Double FALSE, double with Integer FALSE, byte with Byte TRUE e.t.c. And I want to know it is exists "smart solution" for this checking...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470985/integer-class-vs-int-class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get `int.class` out of `Integer.class` or vice versa that is built into Java. You have to do the comparison manually.

- `Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class)` and the inverse thereof return `false` because it does not account for autoboxing (which is compiler generated code)
- the only sign that you're dealing with a primitive type is [`Class#isPrimitive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29) which returns true for `int.class` (also `void.class`) but doesn't for `int[].class`, `Integer.class` for example.
- `Integer.TYPE` and similar are aliases for `int.class`, ..

The smartest way to do this is to use a library or to write a few lines of code that cover all cases. There are only exactly 8 (`boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`) primitive types (+ `void`).

Answer (score 0):

@Sotirios Delimanolis, @WhiteboardDev thanks for leads. I have resolved this this way:

```
public class Types {

private Map<Class, Class> mapWrapper_Primitive;

public Types(){
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive = new HashMap<>();
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Boolean.class, boolean.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Byte.class, byte.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Character.class, char.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Double.class, double.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Float.class, float.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Integer.class, int.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Long.class, long.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Short.class, short.class);
    this.mapWrapper_Primitive.put(Void.class, void.class);
}

public boolean areDerivedTypes(Class type1, Class type2){
    // Checking object types
    if(!type1.isPrimitive() && !type2.isPrimitive()){
        return type1.equals(type2);
    }

    // Checking primitive types
    Class typeA = toPrimitiveType(type1);
    Class typeB = toPrimitiveType(type2);        
    return typeA.equals(typeB);
}

public Class toPrimitiveType(Class type){
    Class value = this.mapWrapper_Primitive.get(type);
    if(value != null){ 
        return value;
    }

    return type;
}
}
```