# How to convert Integer.class (and other boxed) to int.class (and other primitives)?

Tags: java, primitive-types

Is there a way to convert `Integer.class` to `int.class`, and so on for the rest of primitive types?

Something like:

```
jshell> Boolean.class.isPrimitive()
$1 ==> false
jshell> Boolean.class.asPrimitive() == boolean.class
$2 ==> true
```

Comment: first thing `int` is not a class it is a primitive and java will automatically conver this using concept called autoboxing and unboxing

Comment: I'm asking about `int.class` which is a `Class`

Comment: this will helo you understand what is `Integer.class` and `int.class` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470985/integer-class-vs-int-class

Comment: No.  You have to make your own `Map` of wrapper classes to primitive types.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to be more clear about what you mean when you say "convert Integer.class to int.class". What are you trying to do specifically? Note that, when you use reflection, even if a field or method parameter is of type "int.class", the value you obtain for the field or pass to the parameter via reflection is still a wrapper (i.e. Integer.class)

Comment: @MarcioLucca I have a dictionary type structure where I can get and save a value with a string key and a class tag. I want it to behave in the same manner for `int.class` and `Integer.class`, i.e (`dict.get('foo", int.class)` is the same as `dict.get("foo", Integer.class)`

Comment: In that case I'm afraid there is no way to convert, you would have to test for both types individually:
```
Class<?> cls = dict.get("foo");
if (cls == int.class || cls == Integer.class) {
    // do common behavior
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this with `ClassUtils` from [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#primitivesToWrappers-java.lang.Class...-):

```
jshell> import org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils

jshell> ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(int.class)
$1 ==> class java.lang.Integer

jshell> ClassUtils.wrapperToPrimitive(Float.class)
$2 ==> float
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java SE method for it, but it’s easy to keep a Map:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> wrapperToPrimitive = Map.of(
    Void.class, void.class,
    Boolean.class, boolean.class,
    Byte.class, byte.class,
    Character.class, char.class,
    Short.class, short.class,
    Integer.class, int.class,
    Long.class, long.class,
    Float.class, float.class,
    Double.class, double.class);
```